# Execute python script from azure data factory

Tags: python, azure, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks, azure-triggers

Can someone help me with executing python function from azure data factory.
I have stored python function in blob and i'm trying to trigger the same.
However i'm not able to do it. Please assist.

Second, Can i parameterize python function call from ADF?

Answer (score 1):

You could get an idea of [Azure Function Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-azure-function-activity) in ADF which allows you to run Azure Functions in a Data Factory pipeline.

And you could duplicate your python function into [Python Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-function-python).

Also,it want to pass parameters into python function,you could set them into body properties.

[image]

The Azure Function Activity supports routing. For example, if your app uses the following routing - `https://functionAPP.azurewebsites.net/api/functionName/{value}?code=<secret>` - then the functionName is `functionName/{value}`, which you can parameterize to provide the desired `functionName` at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @JayGong. I'm not working on web api, my requirement is to pass parameter from adf and call the python function stored in blob. Is this possible ? or is there any alternative?